# Player WEB para ASF

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com problemas ao tentar criar um **player de vídeo** em `html` para executar arquivos em `ASF`.

No `html` puro, não reproduz nesse formato e a empresa onde trabalho, só aceita esse formato de vídeo.

Existe alguma forma de reproduzir esse tipo no `html`?

Comment: As vezes te ajuda... https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/how-to-play-asf-file-from-html-page-14875/

Comment: eu cheguei a ler isso mas não entendi muito bem como implementar, quando uso ele apresenta a msg de plugin incompatível